# How can i download a text file from the server folder not inside project solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, download

I want to download the textfile on button click from Kendo grid rows. I got an Id of selected row and pass it to my
controller and now it doesnt download the file as it is showing the error below. Thou the error seems to be fixed

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

The file naming is like this :  e669a7e7-7eb2-4cfa-b950-3b79ed621a57

```
public ActionResult DownloadIndex(int id)
{
    try
    {
        string Filelocation = "MyServerLocationFolder";
        OnePossModel md = new Models.OnePossModel();
        JsonParamBuilder myBuilder = new JsonParamBuilder();
        myBuilder.AddParam<Guid>("userid", System.Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        myBuilder.AddParam<int>("id", Convert.ToInt32(id));

        string jsonReq = Models.JsonWrapper.JsonPOST(ApiBaseUrl +  "/WriteFile", myBuilder.GetJSonParam());
        string poassFilename = Models.DeserialiseFromJson<string>.DeserialiseApiResponse(jsonReq);

        string filepath = Filelocation + poassFilename.ToString();
        byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {

            FileName = poassFilename,
            Inline = true,
        };
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + poassFilename + "\"");
        return File(filedata, "application/txt", Server.UrlEncode(poassFilename)); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get "application/txt"?

Answer (score 0):

Use "text/plain" instead of "application/txt":

```
public ActionResult DownloadIndex(int id)
{
    try
    {
        string Filelocation = "MyServerLocationFolder";
        OnePossModel md = new Models.OnePossModel();
        JsonParamBuilder myBuilder = new JsonParamBuilder();
        myBuilder.AddParam<Guid>("userid", System.Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        myBuilder.AddParam<int>("id", Convert.ToInt32(id));

        string jsonReq = Models.JsonWrapper.JsonPOST(ApiBaseUrl +  "/WriteFile", myBuilder.GetJSonParam());
        string poassFilename = Models.DeserialiseFromJson<string>.DeserialiseApiResponse(jsonReq);

        string filepath = Filelocation + poassFilename.ToString();
        byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

        return File(filedata, "text/plain", Server.UrlEncode(poassFilename)); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working, this is the error i got : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'possID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DownloadIndex(Int32)' in 'TTAF.Portal.Parts.Web.Controllers.PossController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: what is `possID`? it is some parameter in your action method, that you trying to call.